# Where to report Ubuntu 14.04.5 nvidia-370 prime select black screen issue?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

Recently I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04.4 to 14.04.5 as my HWE stack support ran out.

I'm also using ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa for latest proprietary nvidia drivers.

My notebook is a Gigabyte P35W v2, with a core i7 and a nvidia GTX 870m.

About a year ago I had this [black screen issue](https://vxlabs.com/2015/02/05/solving-the-ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-346-nvidia-prime-black-screen-issue/), after switching from the on cpu intel card to the dedicated nvidia card with `prime-select nvidia`. It could be resolved by setting the intel driver entry in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to modesetting and a `chattr +i /etc/X11/xorg.conf`. As explained on the link above, it looks like gpu-manager is rewriting `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with the wrong driver, resulting in the black screen.

There was an update to this issue, as I conveniently could switch GPUs with prime-select again before upgrading to 14.04.5. This issue is occurring again after the upgrade, and could be solved again with above solution. It was working fine with nvidia-370 and 14.04.4 before. So I guess the ubuntu-driver-package containing gpu-manager in 14.04.5 is causing this (again?).

My question now is, where do I have to report this issue so the package gets fixed again?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the bug has been already reported:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1610476